# Ubuntu 16.04: Local websites are auto redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, apache-http-server

I know this question has been asked many a time before this and I already tried all the possible solutions that are available on the net. Since nothing had worked for me, I am posting mine with the configuration I have in my Ubuntu 16.04 system.

I would hope that the question would not be deleted or downvoted. I am looking forward to a permanent solution that works and stops auto-redirection to `HTTPS`.

Chrome Version: 87.0.4280.88 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   local.hellotest.com
```

**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
<Directory /var/www/wp-projects/emfl21/test>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I have only one `index.php` file inside `/var/www/wp-projects/emfl21/test` with the following piece of code:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello from test';
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/local.hellotest.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@local.hellotest.com
    ServerName local.hellotest.com

    ServerAlias local.hellotest.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I enabled the site using `sudo a2ensite local.hellotest.com.conf` and finally restarted the server: `sudo service apache2 restart`

Everything went well, but when I am running `local.hellotest.com`, I am ending up at `https://local.hellotest.com` with the following error message:

[image]

I configured many sites in the same process before but never came across this problem. I tried changing the domain name from `local.hellotest.com` to `local.hellotest.test` and making necessary changes in `.conf` files but nothing worked.

Both `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and `Empty cache and hard reload` option failed as well.

Is there any other workaround to come out of this situation?

**UPDATE**
I have a number of sites already set up as `.com` and they are running absolutely fine. The problem is appearing only when I configure a new site.

Comment: Why are you using a `.com` for local development? Just use `hellotest.local`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I `.local` and additionally `.test` as well. But nothing is working. Moreover, I already have a number of sites already set up as `.com` and they are running fine. The problem is appearing when I configure a new site.